# facebook post images from php url

Tags: php, facebook, image, blob

i have a mysql table where i store all the images uploaded by users (in a blob column).

To show the images on my website I use a simple script, like this:

```
  $res = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM table WHERE id=$id");
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
  header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
  echo $row['dvdimage'];
```

and then i call the image with: **`< img src="script.php?id=1" />`**

Everything works fine in my website, the image is shown, but when I share the link or post the image on facebook the thumbnail of the image is not visible...

I don't understand if the error is mine (for example I just have to add some headers in the script.php file, or i can use htaccess to resolve the problem)

...or if the blob/php is a bad practice to store the images in this case..

Answer (score 0):

When you share a link on Facebook it crawl the url and fetch data. You can check [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) what data is Facebook getting from your url.

To tell Facebook what information to show using og tags. Adding headers are not enough to Facebook to detect content.

Check [here](http://ogp.me/) to get more info about open graph protocol.